# Wordpress and using wp_query and want to increase number of posts in the loop

Tags: wordpress

I think I'm missing something super obvious but I'm still learning the architecture of Wordpress and I'm drawing a blank.

A friend gave me a blank theme to practice with. The main home index loop looks like below, with paging. I would like to increase the per-page results from the current value (10) to a much larger value (50).

I have searched Wordpress.org, looking through the wp_query et. al. to no avail.

```
<div id="content">
    <?php /* Top post navigation */ ?>
    <?php global $wp_query; $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; if ( $total_pages > 1 ) { ?>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php /* The Loop — with comments! */ ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>

    <?php /* Create a div with a unique ID thanks to the_ID() and semantic classes with post_class() */ ?>
                    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
    <?php /* an h2 title */ ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is correct, but I am not at a place where I can test it out.
After your global $wp_query  you can let it know how detailed you want the query to be by adding arguments.

```
<?php global $wp_query; 

$wp_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=50');

$total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;  if ( $total_pages > 1 ) { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
query_posts('posts_per_page=50');
```

and if you want to use $wp_query, post_per_page should be able to use as an argument.